# What is the best way to setup a single Google Analytics 4 (GA4) account to track hundreds of subdomains?

Tags: migration, subdomain, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I work with a large university and we track hundreds of subdomains and we also have a few apps.  I'm looking for the best solution as we migrate to GA4.  (I know, should have been done long ago.) We currently have 20+ Properties which all contain up to 25 Views, each configured to track individual subdomains or apps and we grant user access to these individual Views.

With GA4, Views are deprecated.  I'm wondering if anyone has dealt with this type of challenge and how they split up subdomains.  We need to keep one account (if possible) and a general plan of action for breaking up all these domains so we can streamline the Analytics data for our end-users.

We do use Google Tag Manager as well.

So far, we have one "main" GA4 property with a single datastream for the root web.  The app side is not configured.  We also have about 3 other properties setup for individual big players (i.e. colleges or departments which we know will need lots of customizations).

I'm wondering if we should make more properties with multiple "web" datastreams for the many subdomains, but then, how might this affect user engagement with this new Analytics model.  Should we handle this in a completely different way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't make properties for stakeholders. You make properties for tracked activity types. Duplicating the tracking is not a good solution.

You don't have the views, but you have the hostname dimension which you can use to filter reports. Feel free to make hostname-based segments and teach your stakeholders use them.

Finally, native app tracking is done through Firebase. Firebase can then be linked to GA4 as its own stream. Better to keep in the same property you keep the web data.

The general rule is: Don't make additional properties unless you know what you're doing. Additional properties will increase complexity on both ends: the collection and the post-processing of data. Increasing complexity needlessly is just pure incompetence that will make many people frown upon it when they inherit your design.